# Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory

Tags: html

I want to redirect to a page in root directory from a page within a  Admin directory. But i am getting the following error.

**Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.**

Comment: What operating system, web server and scripting language?

Comment: I am using asp.net as scripting language.
like Response.redirect("abc.aspx?RedirectUrl=1");
if i dont send querystring then this works fine.

actually i want set  master page file of a page redirected to. and master page file is in admin folder based on query string value.